# Protractor controlflow scheduler not handling anonymous function declaration and execution in thenable manner

Tags: protractor, anonymous

Here is example code:

```
//some code in "OuterFunction"
var outterProm = protractor.promise.Deferred();
(function doMore(arg){
    var innerProm = protractor.promise.Deffered();
    callSomeFunctionWhichReturnsPromise().then(function(value){
         //code to process value
         innerProm.fulfill();
    };
    return innerProm;
})("something").then(function(){
outterProm.fulfill();
});
```

I am observing that protractor schedules and then begins executing OutterFunction but when it comes across the doMore function declaration (during OutterFunction execution) it schedules doMore, but not executes doMore... resulting in then attempting to continue exec of OutterFunction resulting in a .then() call on the doMore return value (which is undefined because doMore never executed to return the promise).

Am I correct on this? Would this be a protractor issue? Any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

I mis-troubleshoot'd the code.

The issue is that:
    var prom = protractor.promise.Deferred();

should be:
    var prom = new protractor.promise.Deferred();

Hence, my original question is no longer valid.